# Riled Up Riley Riddle 1

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My prefix is an endless path

That has a lot of crazy math

My infix is appearing here

Multiple times in this riddle near

My suffix is a word kids dislike

Since they won't be able to entertain their psyche

Put them together and you'll see why

I want you to deduce... what am I?

P.S. Shout out to Cubemaster for introducing me to these kinds of riddles

This should clear things up

> It is a musical instrument, I'll try to give better clues in the next Riley Riddle

Comment: Sorry if this is easy, I've never tried making a Riley Riddle before

Comment: Well if this is your first time, then somebody has talent ;D

Comment: Shoot, I messed up on the infix, since I don't have a good understanding of what an infix is. Focus on the prefix and suffix, then find the missing letter

Comment: I think the infix is also known as the postfix, particularly when coding, or something. All these, the prefixes and suffixes and infixes are altogether known as **affixes** or rarely, **morphemes** (like how $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ are known as the (natural, counting) numbers). You can [go here](http://english.edurite.com/literary-response/affixes.html) for some detailed information. Regarding the "postfix" idea, you can [go here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/fix.html) if you are interested :)

Comment: I looked with the infix is, seems to be a "word in a word" of sorts

Comment: @XavierStanton just like the prefix and suffix, the infix is one part of the word. But while the **pre**fix is at the start of the word, and the suffix at the end, the **in**fix is somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are

> Piano

My prefix is an endless path

That has a lot of crazy math

> Pi is an irrational number and goes on indefinitely.

My infix is appearing here

Multiple times in this riddle near

> "A", You use articles in this riddle multiple times.

My suffix is a word kids dislike

Since they won't be able to entertain their psyche

> NO! you can't play!

And after all

> It's an instrument.

Comment: Yes, I had to add that once I realized how vague the riddle was. My 2nd one is better, I promise ;)

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> afterschool?

My prefix is an endless path
That has a lot of crazy math

> AFT - Angular(or Arithmetic) Fourier Transform

My infix is appearing here
Multiple times in this riddle near

> could be R, because **R**iled Up **R**iley **R**iddle

My suffix is a word kids dislike

> Well, kids usually don't like going to school :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> "ORDEAL"

My prefix is an endless path

> O looks like a circle and a circle is an endless path

That has a lot of crazy math

> O also looks like zero, and there is a whole mathematic science behind the digit zero

My infix is appearing here

> O*R*DEAL and he*r*e

Multiple times in this riddle near

> Well I got this one from Eutherpy: multiple *R* 's in the title

My suffix is a word kids dislike

Since they won't be able to entertain their psyche

> This could be the part where my answer don't fit, because ORDEAL is the whole word and not just the suffix. But the meaning could fit: suffer, trouble

Comment: No, sorry about this riddle

Answer (score 1):

Could you be

> a PIERCING?

My prefix is an endless path

> PI - Pi has infinite digits

That has a lot of crazy math

> Each digit of Pi has to be calculated, and you must be crazy to try to define Pi exactly (no offense :P).

My infix is appearing here
multiple times in this riddle near

> R - most words in title start with 'R' 
>  (credits to eutherpy)

My suffix is a word kids dislike
Since they won't be able to entertain their psyche

> SING - I must admit this is quite far-fetched. Children do not listen to the meaning of songs, they more or less just sing along. (again, no offense). Adults are more prone to look deeper into the lyrics and like to interpret it somehow, thereby 'entertaining their psyche'.

Put them together and you'll see why
I want you to deduce... what am I?

> put together it spells "PIRSING", and after some real hard thinking and using my extraterrestrial deduction abilities I saw that it looks and sounds like PIERCING. Problem is, the same deduction abilities tell me that this is not the right solution. After the first two parts I had "PIR" but "ATE" did not work for the suffix part, neither did "ANHA". So i had to be inventive - but hey the question is tagged wordplay so I thought lets play a bit ^^.